# How can I get the expire time for the particular item in memcached

Tags: python, memcached

In runtime, I want to retrieve the expire time info about some items in memcached. I didn't find any related interface on memcached. Can I do this? something like:
mc.get_expire_time('key')

Thank you

Comment: It's not limited to python, if there are any kind language or lib could do this.

Comment: Python API's on this page: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to memcache protocol (both [text](http://code.sixapart.com/svn/memcached/trunk/server/doc/protocol.txt) and [binary](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/MemcacheBinaryProtocol)) niether `get` nor `gets` return expiration time. And there is no other method to retrieve it. But sure you can pack expiration time into value along with what you store now when you `set`/`add` it to make it retrievable.

Comment: the link for the text documentation is broken, perhaps this is useful: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Answer (score 26):

Python memcache API doesn't provide such functionalities. However you can telnet into memcached to dump all keys and expiration time.

```
> telnet localhost 11211
```

`stats items` show the slabs that contain your data.

```
stats items
STAT items:12:number 1108
...
END
```

Then use `stats cachedump slab_id count` to see the key and expiration time. Set count to 0 to retrieve all keys.

```
stats cachedump 12 1
ITEM abc [100 b; 1528336485 s]
END
```

Comment: A blog post explain we can only dump one page per slab class (1MB of data). In my cases it means 32771 keys: https://lzone.de/blog/How-to%20Dump%20Keys%20from%20Memcache

Answer (score 10):

Annoyingly, this information only seems to be provided in the slab stats.  Start with this:

```
[$]> (sleep 1; echo "stats cachedump 1 0"; sleep 1; echo "quit";) | telnet localhost 11211 | grep 'my_key'
```

and increment the slab (the first number after 'cachedump') until you find the appropriate slab.  Once you get a result, it'll be of the form

```
ITEM my_key [2 b; 1389767076 s]
```

The last number there (`1389767076` in this case) is the [unixtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixtime) when the key will expire.  You can convert this number to something more human-readable with Python's [`time.localtime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) or on-the-fly using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1389767076+unixtime).

Comment: There's some code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/636/review-request-python-class-w-telnet-interface-to-memcached that takes care of almost everything required to follow this approach.

Comment: first line returns: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

If you are not critical on accuracy, I have thought about creating your own client that talks via binary protocol and storing expiration time in the Flag field of ExtraLength. https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped#set-add-replace

Here, in the 8 bytes extra, the last four are storing TTL, you can use the first 4 to store expiration time. And when you GET it back, it's still in that flag field.

The down side of this is:

- Writing your own client.
- You have to base on local clock to calculate expiration time
- You only have 4 bytes to store an expiration time in integer.